# Laravel file_put_contents error on shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel

I created my Laravel app and I am uploading on shared hosting. It's show error:

> file_put_contents(D:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\storage\framework/sessions/FlEPsHNW7Rggfb9wvDZ71K7D2YQNNQK0epRBRQnW):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory

This is folder from my computer. I read same problems but I am on shared hosting and I don't have a composer or artisan for operations.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: well there's no `D:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\storage\framework/sessions/FlEPsHNW7Rggfb9wvDZ71K7D2YQNNQK0epRBRQnW` in your shared host if I'm guessing right !! I mean **D:\xampp...** noway

Comment: You probably need to clear some cache or something, because there's still your local xampp configuration somewhere

Comment: Yes, this folder does not exist. It's from my computer.

Comment: How I clear cache? I don't have artisan

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you should do is looking for occurrences of `xampp` in your application because it seems you have sessions that are written to same folder that you have on your machine and obviously such directory doesn't exist on web server.

Especially make sure you in `session.php` you have:

```
'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
```

and remove config cache from `bootstrap/cache` directory just in case

Comment: 'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'), -> this is right. In bootstrap/cache hasn't cache

Comment: And have you searched for all occurrences of `xampp` already?

Comment: Yes, I searched.

Comment: It has to be somewhere. In case you are using very custom code you should search it also in database dump

Comment: As I said there is no way - there should be `xampp` somewhere. Webhosting haven't used `D:\xampp` from nowhere for sure so it has to be somewhere in files when you copied it or in database if you used custom configuration

Comment: Oh yeah. I found this path in boostrap/cache/config.php. Now how I change?

Comment: Just a moment before you don't have file in this directory :) Just remove this file - it's for performance reasons only. If you care about performance I would recommend you to use VPS not shared hosting

Comment: I removed file, but will it harm the project?

Comment: No, it will only affect performance a bit. If you care as I said use VPS and run `php artisan config:cache` to cache it or you can run this from your code but this is completely other thing.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue here.
I tried to run `php artisan config:cache` but it didn't work out

Then I delete all my sessions in `/myprojectname/storage/framework/` but still didn't work out on shared hosting but worked fine on localhost.

Here's what worked:

I delete the cache folder in `/myprojectname/bootstrap/` and ran the application and got this error:

```
Exception thrown with message "The /hosthome/hostuser/myprojectname/bootstrap/cache directory must be present and writable."
```

I then made a new cache folder in `/myprojectname/bootstrap/` and ran the site and it was up

**in short terms**

- Navigate to your projects `/bootstrap/cache/` folder.
- Delete the contents of the directory and your good to go

Comment: The files are created again once you run the website again.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I had renamed the existing ones to .old e.g config.php.old just to be safe . But it's worked well and the files were recreated the files when I reloaded the site url.

Answer (score 0):

Change config path  and make sure storage folder has correct permission 
[Directory Permissions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/installation)

After installing Laravel, you may need to configure some permissions. Directories within the storage and the bootstrap/cache directories should be writable by your web server or Laravel will not run. If you are using the Homestead virtual machine, these permissions should already be set.

Answer (score 0):

cleared the cache for me

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34064142)

Comment: Specifically, this is a response to a comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the entire file from the bootstrap/cache folder.

In my case its working fine.