# Laravel InvalidArgumentException in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: laravel, google-app-engine

I published my project on Google Cloud Platform (with gCloud). But these are the errors:

First Error:

> at FileViewFinder->findInPaths('welcome',
>   array('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project-laravel/resources/views'))

Second error in other route:

> file_put_contents(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project-laravel/storage/framework/views/0e930ae47a8b122c0468c37872fd9792aed8b643.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory

In my local, I clear cache and updated the composer. And after that, I published the code. How can I fix these errors in GCP?

Comment: Try run `php artisan opt`.

Answer (score 0):

> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project-laravel/storage/framework/views/0e930ae47a8b122c0468c37872fd9792aed8b643.php

Is a path on your Macintosh, it doesn't exists on App Engine. Consider this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47080822/8831875), which talks about the exactly same issue but for Windows with XAMP.